# prove by induction the sequence

Tags: summation, induction

I want to show by induction that
$$ 1- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}
$$

The base case I thought of is n=1, so we can simply show $\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, but how do I proceed to the inductive step?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Update your question with how you can try the inductive step - (a) what do you actually assume (b) what do you need to prove (c) how can you try to prove it

Comment: Straightforward induction works.  Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.

Comment: What my previous comment intends is that, assuming that this is an assigned problem, you should have received training (AKA Tools) in how to prove an assertion via Mathematical Induction.  Per MathSE protocol, you are expected to edit your question to explain the tools that you have been presented with, perhaps with a sample Math Induction problem that you were taught about.  Then, you are supposed to edit your posting with a good faith effort, showing work, where you try to use the tools to solve the problem.  Then, a MathSE reviewer is allowed to provide specific help.

Comment: Hint: let call $E_n=\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots+\frac 1{2n}$ note that $-E_n=E_n-2E_n$ then regroup positive and negative terms.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the left side $A_n$ and the right side $B_n$. Now you've taken care of the base case. Let's do the inductive step. If $A_n=B_n$ is true then consider $A_{n+1}=A_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$. Now similarly $$B_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+2}=B_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}
\\=B_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{2}{2n+2}=B_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$$
But $B_n=A_n$ by the induction hypothesis so the proof follows.